# Cakephp is not redirecting properly when pages are cached

Tags: cakephp, caching, redirect

I am having some issues with a site that was working correctly until i implemented full page caching in CakePHP.

I have followed the guidance in the Manual and have my $session->flash in a no-cache block as so:

```
<cake:nocache>
    <? 
    if($session->check('Message.flash')){
        $session->flash();
    } 
    ?>
</cake:nocache>
```

However, whenever a controller sets a flash message and redirects to a cached page the page loads down to the  tag and then gives the error:

```
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object
[CORE/cake/libs/view/helpers/session.php, line 145]

Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::renderLayout() in
/home/decipherd/domains/example.com/public_html/beta/cake/libs/view/helpers/session.php
on line 14
```

If i then go to a page created by another controller the correct (delayed) message is displayed and the page loads correctly.

I have now submitted this to the CakePHP trac as [ticket 282](http://code.cakephp.org/tickets/view/282)

Comment: also just to make sure, what version of cake are you using?

Comment: You might consider upgrading to 1.2.5 Stable if that's a possibility, many changes have been made to the Core.

Comment: I have upgraded to 1.2.5 Stable now, and the same issue occurs.. i get the error above until i go to page which uses another controller.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it might be an issue with the core, have you tried [submitting a bug report](http://code.cakephp.org/tickets)?

Comment: Looking into the core code of the SessionHelper, it appears that it's not an issue with the $session object not existing in the view, but an object with the key 'view' not being able to be retrieved from the ClassRegistry when you call $session->flash().  When you turn caching on, Cake probably has code that does not create a 'view' object, which then causes the issue you're seeing.  You'll probably need to submit a bug report, or alternatively, manually display the contents of $session->read('Message.flash.message');

Comment: As i can't afford for to wait for the bug report to be fixed i am going to give manually displaying the contents ago and will report back, thanks

Comment: Matt, i can read the flash message manually but as you cannot write to the session from a view i cannot remove it afterwards, so the message keeps displaying on subsequent pages - any ideas?

Comment: The SessionHelper's del method still exists, so immediately after you read from it, just call $session->del('Message.flash');

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that there is something in the flash message? Try:

```
debug($session->read());
```

OR to output it to the debug.log

```
$this->log($session->read(), LOG_DEBUG); // this might not work in the view?
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error message, it seems as is SessionHelper is not available for some reason.

I am not sure why exactly, this helper is usually loaded automatically when using AuthComponent or SessionComponent in your application.

Just a guess, but it might be worth putting `$helpers = array('Session', ...);` in your problem controller or AppController for good measure.

You can inspect everything available to your view with `debug($this);`

Ultimately, I would take Matt's advice and upgrade to the latest stable version anyway.

Comment: I have upgraded to the latest stable and added 'Session' to the helpers array. It appears as though the SessionHelper has loaded correctly, although the same error is occuring..